# "observation + About " Or "observation + On"

Tags: prepositions, verbs

I want to say:

**This technique is based on an observation we made about/on the theorem of ...**"

**Question:** In the above sentence which one should I use, "about" or "on" or neither ?

To clarify the theorem has already exist but we made a new observation about/on the theorem.

Comment: "observations **of**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is correct, and you can find current examples of both.

[This American tourist's list of observations about small-town Britain has gone surprisingly viral](http://i100.independent.co.uk/article/this-american-tourists-list-of-observations-about-smalltown-britain-has-gone-surprisingly-viral--WkxJmGT_NDx)

[A 5 year old's observations on the Republican debate](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2015/09/17/1422059/-A-5-year-old-s-observations-on-the-Republican-debate#)

In my opinion, "observations on" is slightly more old-fashioned and formal.  Here is a Google ngrams search showing the declining use of "observation on" and the increasing use of "observation about": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=observation+on%2Cobservation+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobservation%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobservation%20about%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'd say it's almost certain both of your cited usages carry the sense [*a **statement** based on something one has seen, heard, or noticed*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/observation), whereas in OP's context he means *the **action or process** of closely observing or monitoring something or someone*. For the former sense, ***make** [an] observation[s]* is such a well-established usage that native speakers usually use a different verb such as ***conduct, carry out, perform*** when they mean the latter.

Comment: (The "decline" shown by your chart is entirely due to the fact that the "statement" sense is increasingly seen as a dated/formal/flowery usage.)